# Php script for sending pdf files to a server

Tags: php

first time posting here. I'm trying to write a PHP script that will copy and send certain pdf files to a server. I have a query from which it will pull the ID numbers of the pdfs that need to be sent. Now I don't know if the script is not connecting correctly or if the script isn't fetching anything. Also, I made a check test at the bottom of the script to see if the pdfs have been successfully sent or not. Any help would be appreciated.
P.S.: I'm getting a error "Notice: Undefined offset" for the line: Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->update("transfers", array("transfer_status" => 0), array("id = ?" => $id[0]));

```
    public function transfertoAction(){
     $time_start = microtime(true);
            $errors = array();
            $data = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->fetchAll("
                    SELECT id
                    FROM transfers
                    LIMIT 1
                    ");

                foreach ($data as $id) {
                    $srcBookChapter = "/var/www/sites/CDN/pdfs/$id.pdf";

                    $dstBookChapter = "/name/wheretopaste";

                    $ftpUsername = "username";
                    $ftpUserpass = "userpass";
                    $ftpServer = "server";
                    $ftpPort = "22";

                    $connection = ssh2_connect($ftpServer, $ftpPort);
                    ssh2_auth_password($connection, $ftpUsername, $ftpUserpass);



                    try {

                        if (!file_exists($srcBookChapter)) {
                            throw new Exception("Could not find file: $srcBookChapter");
                        }

                        $sftpStream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://".$sftp.$dstBookChapter, 'w');

                        if (!$sftpStream) {
                            throw new Exception("Could not open remote file: $dstBookChapter");
                        }

                        if (!file_exists($srcBookChapter)) {
                            throw new Exception("Could not find file: $srcBookChapter");
                        }

                        $data_to_send = file_get_contents($srcBookChapter);

                        if ($data_to_send === false) {
                            throw new Exception("Could not open local file: $dstBookChapter.");
                        }

                        if (fwrite($sftpStream, $data_to_send) === false) {
                            throw new Exception("Could not send data from file: $dstBookChapter.");
                        }

                        Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->update("transfers", array("transfer_status" => 1), array("id = ?" => $id[0]));
                        fclose($sftpStream);

                    } catch (Exception $e) {

                        Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->update("transfers", array("transfer_status" => 0), array("id = ?" => $id[0]));
                        $error = ('Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
                        $errors[] .= $error;

                    }

        }

        $time_end = microtime(true);
        $time = $time_end - $time_start;
        zdd('Finished in ' . $time . ' seconds');
        zddd('Done');
}
```

Comment: Surely the first thing to do is to find out whether the script is not fetching anything, or whether it's not connecting properly? What is actually happening that should not, or not happening that should? You suggest there's an issue but don't say what it is.

Comment: And, you use `$sftp` to open the server for writing, but don't define it anywhere.

Comment: Slightly O/T, but if I were you I'd check that the source file exists before opening it on the FTP server. ETA - Oh, I see that you do check before the FTP open. _And_ after.